# ScrollBar Setting jQuery / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Как отредактировать скролл бар внутри дропдауна? 
У меня есть PSD макет, сделал кнопку с дропдауном, в нем пункты, надо что бы етот DropDown был ограничен, и был скролл бар `overflow:auto;` я его добавил к выпадающему блоку и в блоке есть стандартный ползунок, а как теперь приклеить из PSD макета или  отредактировать ползунок ( jQuery / CSS )?
Где можно посмотреть очень подробные примеры?
( без скролл дорожки для ползунка ).
Мой дропдаун буттон:

```
            <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"></button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых нужно понять, что все, что здесь написано, не будет на 100% кроссбраузерным.
Во-вторых, это только то, что мне удалось найти по простому запросу в гугле:
1. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/
2. https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/
Здесь примеры с codepen'а:
1. http://codepen.io/MathieuRichard/pen/HAgnm
2. http://codepen.io/GhostRider/pen/GHaFw (этот - **мой любимый**)

По сути же все делается просто при помощи `webkit-skrollbar` `wbkit-scrollbar-track` и подобных вещей. Но сразу обратите внимание, что это справедливо только для **chrome**-подобных браузеров.

P.S. Если вам не нужна сколл-дорожка (`webkit-scrollbar-track` свойство), то установите ему цвет `transparent`, ну или просто цвет родительского блока.

Comment: Пасибки, помогло

Comment: @BonBonSlick Если помогло решение, то помечайте его правильным (галочка слева от ответа) и говорите спасибо (стрелочка вверх слева от ответа).